# Java compiler doesn't complain that `No return statement` if I use while true

Tags: java

I have following code, the compiler should complain that `No return statement`, but the code works fine.

If I remove the `while(true)` code block, then the compiler works and complains `No return statement`, I would like to know how the compiler works here.

```
public class ReturnTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(check());
    }

    public static boolean check() {
        int i = 0;
        while (true) { //(1) 
            if (i >= 100) {
                return true;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why should that code complain? I agree it looks a bit odd, but you're basically in an endless loop until you 'return true'. if you remove the while -> there is no loop after the else block that leads to the return statement

Comment: Why do you think it "should" complain?

Comment: Anything after `while (true)` is unreachable unless you `break` out of the loop.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the compiler knows that, if there's an endless while loop, there's never going to be a return.

Comment: Why should it? It can see that the `while` doesn't exit just as well as you can. Maybe better.

Comment: BTW if you had any statement after the loop, including a `return`, the compiler should complain it is unreachable since the `wile` statement never completes normally, as given in Java Language Specification [14.22. Unreachable Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.22-300-Q)

Comment: + you do not get an error in posted code since the method never can complete normally, JLS [8.4.7. Method Body](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.7-240): "**If a method is declared to have a return type (§8.4.5), then a compile-time error occurs if the body of the method can complete normally (§14.1).**
*In other words, a method with a return type must return only by using a return statement that provides a value return; the method is not allowed to "drop off the end of its body". See §14.17 for the precise rules about return statements in a method body.*"

Comment: @user16320675 You have this back to front. The method 'completes normally' by executing the `return` statement in the only code path that can reach it. The part after the `while` loop is unreachable in this case so it does not figure in this evaluation.

Comment: @user207421 I don't think so, maybe my wording was inconsistent - I should have written "since the **body of the method** never can complete normally", which is what I meant by "since the **method** never can complete normally" (not to be confused with "*method call*".) A `return` statement *always completes abruptly*! So does the *body of the method* if `return` is executed in it

Answer (score 2):

The compiler realizes: The while statement either returns, or continues looping (and returns later). Since the while statement is effectively terminal in the method (and can't pass the execution further down), any code below that while statement is considered "dead code" (since it can't be reached), and thus a return isn't needed.

Comment: To add to that: Not only is the return statement not needed, it is also not even allowed! Everything after the while loop is considered to be unreachable and by putting a return statement there, the code doesn't compile anymore.